# Symfony Heroku Deployment: Assets Not Accessible

Tags: apache, symfony, ubuntu, heroku

I have a Symfony 2.7 app which works fine in the local dev environment and on an AWS Ubuntu ec2 instance. I'm migrating it to Heroku and I'm able to login, but all web asset (css/img/js) requests result in a `403 (Forbidden)` in the browser console.

The Heroku logs show, for example:

```
AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible
```

In my `composer.json`, under the 'extra' node, I have:

```
"symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
```

I'm not currently using assetic.

**Things I've tried**

Running `heroku run bash` and heading to my app's web directory, I see:

```
~/web/bundles $ ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u46658 46658   85 Jun 24 13:56 mybundle -> /tmp/build_0940aedabf55a47c5c407ff7b7a58c58/src/MyApp/MyBundle/Resources/public
```

However I can't `cd` into the `mybundle` directory, nor into the `/temp/...` directory ('No such file or directory').

As this appears to be because Apache isn't following symlinks, I also tried a `php app/console assets:install`, which yielded 'Installing assets as hard copies', and then cleared the cache (with `app/console cache:clear`) but the problem remained the same. `php app/check.php` gives me the A-OK.

Any ideas, or any more information I can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from

```
"symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
```

To

```
"symfony-assets-install": "relative"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following to the `scripts` key in composer.json:

```
    "compile": [
      "app/console assets:install"
    ]
```

I believe this is related to the heroku ephemeral file system, which apparently resists file system changes after a deploy. Interesting that performing an `app/console assets:install` in the heroku bash shell doesn't result in an error, but also doesn't fix the problem, while issuing the same command during deployment does.